# replace company icons from a website globally

Tags: javascript

If a company changes its icon (e.g., FB to Meta), will a one-liner work to replace all old icons with new ones? Like this:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("old-icon")).forEach((item, ind) => item.src = 'newIcon.png')
```

Any other factors we should consider?

Comment: Why not simply call the new icon "old-icon" then you wouldn't have to make any changes?

Comment: Sorry, but the same time you spent cutting this code bit was more expensive than updating the old "icon/image" to the new one.

You could run the code you wrote to replace these, and it may work.

But my question is...
If you have access to the code in order to run the bit you wrote, why not just update the icon itself?

Comment: About the code bit, you cut...

You can also use `document.querySelectorAll('.cssClassHere')` which returns a list, so you could use the `.forEach` straight away like a more readable way.

If you are modifying/mutating the elements anyway, don't need to clone the list using `Array.from` as well.